# Add a range to $group aggregate

Tags: mongodb

So, I have this to find items that were created on a certain day, the result comes back fine. What I would like to to is limit it to results within the last 7 days. How can I do that?

```
db.leaderboard.aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: {
            year: {$year: "$created"}, 
            month: {$month: "$created"}, 
            day: {$dayOfMonth: "$created"}
        }, 
        count: {"$sum": 1}
    }
})
```

I have this, it works using a `find`, but I can't figure out how to incorporate it with `aggregate`.

```
{
    created: {
        $gt: new Date((new Date()) - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7))
    }
}
```

I have tried placing it after the group, and I get this error: `exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field`

I have tried placing it after `count` and I get this error: `exception: the group aggregate field name '$gt' cannot be an operator name`

What can I do to get these two to work together?

Comment: Did you mean to use a [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add a $match stage to your aggregate

```
 db.leaderboard.aggregate([
    { $match: { created: { $gt: new Date((new Date()) - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7))}}},
     { $group: {
        _id: {
            year: {$year: "$created"}, 
            month: {$month: "$created"}, 
            day: {$dayOfMonth: "$created"}
        }, 
        count: {"$sum": 1}
     }}
    ])
```